# write parsed tokens and YYTEXT of flex lexical analyser to a file

Tags: compiler-construction, flex-lexer, lexical-analysis

I need to write the token and the text parsed of that token in a file with flex analyser. Basically I want to store each parsed token in an output file.

Someone has some idea?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Yes: We have an idea how to do it. You will find of the best experts at writing lexical analysers here. However they will not do all the work for you. You have to do some too. Show us what you have tried so far. What code do you have? Click the edit button to add it. Also, do you want the tokens or the lexemes or both?

Comment: there are tons of examples in the internet, what have you tried?

Comment: I take it you know how flex returns the token and parsed text, and that you know how to write those to a file, so I cannot see what your problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't understand very well how flex works, but after read more, I discover how to solve my problem. I used a simple linked list to save the identifiers.